# vue/cli 3 unmet dependencies

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I tried the latest vue-cli 3 tool...  full install
project setup is done correctly, but as soon as I add a new dependency, I get a list of warnings, unmet dependencies ... is it due to yarn ( I did not test npm..) or not. Anyway to solve them?

```
    $ yarn add vue-i18n
    yarn add v1.9.4
    [1/4]   Resolving packages...
    [2/4]   Fetching packages...
    [3/4]   Linking dependencies...
    warning "@vue/cli-plugin-babel > babel-loader@8.0.0-beta.4" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=2".
    warning "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint > eslint-loader@2.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=2.0.0 <5.0.0".
    warning "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa > workbox-webpack-plugin@3.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
    warning "@vue/eslint-config-prettier > eslint-config-prettier@2.10.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@>=3.14.1".
    warning " > babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
    warning " > sass-loader@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
    [4/4]   Building fresh packages...
    success Saved lockfile.
    success Saved 1 new dependency.
    info Direct dependencies
    └─ vue-i18n@8.0.0
    info All dependencies
    └─ vue-i18n@8.0.0
    ✨  Done in 34.88s.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tl;dr: Probably not a problem except for `webpack` (but still probably not a problem). Since `webpack` is a peer dependency for multiple dependencies, non-deterministic behavior could arise due to different version constraints being listed in different dependencies.

#### What's Going On

Yarn presents these warnings to prevent different dependencies requiring different versions of a third sub-dependency, which may cause non-deterministic behavior. For instance here, `babel-loader`, `eslint-loader`, `workbox-webpack-plugin`, and `sass-loader` all have slightly different version constraints on webpack, which means without a `yarn.lock` file the version constraints are not exactly predictable. To resolve this, you could add `webpack` as an explicit dependency for your project, or you could `yarn upgrade webpack@x.x.x` to the version you desire then rely on your `yarn.lock` to specify this version.

#### The Solution

In your specific case, the only peer dependency you should be worried about is `webpack` because all the other ones are only required by a single dependency. However, its likely that no problems will arise if you were to just do nothing about these warnings.

Ideally, this should have been resolved by Vue in `vue create` process by adding `webpack` to the `package.json`, but since I am able to reproduce this error on my end I am guessing that they have not gotten around to it. I would encourage you to [create an issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues) if one has hasn't already been made for this.

#### More info on Peer Dependencies

A project maintainer can specify peer dependencies in the project's `package.json` when they believe dependency conflicts could arise when using the package. For instance, if you visit the `package.json` for `@vue/cli-plugin-babel` then you will see `webpack@>=2` listed in a `peerDependencies` section. Whoever wrote this Vue plugin likely added `webpack` as a peer dependency because they were aware how popular `webpack` is and wanted to warn the user that this plugin uses `webpack` so as to help them deal with potential conflicts.

While written with `npm` instead of `yarn` in mind, I found [this article](https://medium.com/@jacob.h.page/common-npm-mistakes-51bf8989079f) presents some useful advice for working with peer dependencies and peer dependency warnings.

Comment: This is a `yarn` issue, not a `vue-cli` issue. See: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1503

Comment: @Derek Eh, to an extent. If `Vue` is supposed to scaffold the codebase and generate the `package.json`, it should properly add necessary peer dependencies. I don't see how `yarn` on its own would know how to pick the correct version of a peer dependency that has differing version constraints from different dependencies.

Comment: These issues dont occur on npm

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete answer ...  I am going to get rid of yarn and back to use npm until this issue is solved

Comment: @erwin No worries! Fyi, I tested in `npm`, and I still receive warnings: 
`$ npm install
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-cypress@2.0.1 requires a peer of eslint@>= 3.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

Comment: @erwin @Derek UPDATE: As mentioned at https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/, versions 1 and 2 of `npm` used to automatically install peer dependencies but not so with v3 of `npm`.

Comment: So if not anymore possible with v3 , what is the               process to install peer dependencies?

Comment: @erwin In Yarn at least, sub-dependencies listed as peer dependencies are always installed; it is just that they may be installed multiple times if different dependencies required different versions of them. tl;dr: Ignoring the warnings should be fine, but if you want to be extra safe add peer dependencies as top-level dependencies if multiple dependencies rely on them and specify differing version constraints